# Gradle + Robotium + Jenkins

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, gradle, robotium

I am trying to set up a CI environment with Jenkins and Robotium. I want to use the same project for both built and test, but seems so tricky to get all working. I was wondering if someone had something like that working and if it can publish at least build.gradle and the project structure. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have been running in production for a few months now. See this question for a sample project and video of how to use robotium with gradle.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23295849/1965124

As for the jenkins side of things:

- Install the android sdk on the machine that will be running jenkins
- set up android home variable
- install the android plugin
- run the following tasks from inside a jenkins job: clean connectedAndroidTest
- after running 1 build (it will fail the first time), change the local.properties file to point to the local installation of the android sdk.

Let me know if you need any more pointers, its not as hard as I initially thought it would be.

Answer (score 0):

I configured `TeamCity` as CI server. Also, project builds by `Gradle`.

The main idea is to execute `gradle connectedInstrumentTest`, that task will execute all project's tests on all connected devices, then it will put the test results in standard `ant-junit` format, so then you can set Jenkins to parse `app-folder/build/instrumentTest-results/connected/*.xml` test results.

If you got more questions, you can post them to the comments.